# When can an async operation exit in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

#### Context

I'm reading through [this blog](https://carllerche.com/2021/06/17/six-ways-to-make-async-rust-easier/). some code is provided:

```
async fn parse_line(socket: &TcpStream) -> Result<String, Error> {
    let len = socket.read_u32().await?;
    let mut line = vec![0; len];
    socket.read_exact(&mut line).await?;
    let line = str::from_utf8(line)?;
    Ok(line)
}

loop {
    select! {
        line_in = parse_line(&socket) => {
            if let Some(line_in) = line_in {
                broadcast_line(line_in);
            } else {
                // connection closed, exit loop
                break;
            }
        }
        line_out = channel.recv() => {
            write_line(&socket, line_out).await;
        }
    }
}
```

And the author claims that `parse_line` can end up in a corrupted state if `channel` receives a message while parse_line is executing.

#### Question

At what points can `parse_line` be interrupted? Is it at *any* point? From my current understanding --which may be wrong-- Rust can switch tasks on a thread at await statements but at these points the state is stored so that work can be resumed.

#### What I imagine

I'm imagining that in `parse_line`, Rust is loading bytes into the `line` variable. After reading some number of bytes (and may have only half the bytes for some ASCII character) and while waiting for more to come in, `channel` receives something and the context switches.

After completing the `channel.recv()` task, Rust goes back to reading the input, however the user providing the bytes cancelled the request and now there's nothing else to read.

Now `str::from_utf8(line)?` throws the UTF-8 error since `line` has an incomplete ASCII character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Not at *any* point, only at `.await`s.

---

async code is lowered into state machines that implement [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html). `.await` calls [`Future::poll()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) in a loop, suspending the caller when it returns `Poll::Pending` and finishing on `Poll::Ready`. This essentially runs the inner future to completion.

However, what happens if we call `poll()` few times then stop without completing the future? In this case, the few times that we called `poll()` have advanced the future into some point in its execution, and there we stop. We have *cancelled* the future.

The key observation is that this point of execution must be inside `.await`. That's because synchronous, without-`.await` code in the future translates into direct synchronous code in the `poll()` implementation, and we can't stop there. We can only stop after we returned from `poll()`, and this happens either on the middle of an `.await` or on completion.

However, not all futures are *cancellation safe*. Some, like your `parse_line()`, lose work when they're cancelled. If we cancel at the second `.await`, the length has already been read (and discarded) from the socket but the body hasn't yet, so we lose that length. We cannot recover it, and the next time the function will be invoked it will see corrupted data from the socket (or just skip one record).

`select!` cancels all futures other than the first-completed one, so this code has a bug.

The fix is to never lose the future, but keep it for later:

```rust
let mut parse_line_fut = std::pin::pin!(parse_line(&socket));
loop {
    select! {
        line_in = parse_line_fut.as_mut() => {
            if let Ok(line_in) = line_in {
                broadcast_line(line_in);

                parse_line_fut.set(parse_line(&socket));
            } else {
                // connection closed, exit loop
                break;
            }
        }
        line_out = channel.recv() => {
            write_line(&socket, line_out).await;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clarifying Q: What do you mean by the length has been discarded? I'm assuming the variable is still initialized.

Comment: @financial_physician The value has been read from the stream and is no longer there. The variable is dropped. The value is not stored anywhere.

Comment: How do I know if a variable will persist after a context switch or if it will be dropped?

Comment: @financial_physician Variables within a future are not dropped when the context switches. They are dropped when the future itself is dropped.